# Connecting toggle switch to Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, toggle-switch

I am struggling to make a cockpit for my home-made flight simulation.

How can I connect this toggle switch to an Arduino Uno:

[image]

**Tries:**

I connected one end to "Ground" another to "VCC" and middle one to any analog pin. But it turns off the Arduino.

Please help me to connect this switch correctly.

Comment: it is a switch, similar to a pushbutton ... have you searched the web for tutorials?

Comment: Yes but nothing works. Please help me if it can be connected as similar to pushbuton and I want to get it's state 0 or 1

Comment: You are likely connecting the switch incorrectly, so the switch is connecting vcc directly to ground

Comment: `nothing works` is a meaningless description of a problem ... please update your post with a description of how you connected the switch, the code that you used, what you expected to happen and what actually did happen

Comment: Show a photo. You don't need an analog input. It's on/off so a digital input is all that is required. Again, describe what exactly happens when you toggle the switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arduino related question goes here: [Arduino SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLODcH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

```
#define switch 3

void setup(){
 pinMode(switch, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop(){
 if(switch == LOW){
  do this;
 } else {
  do that;
 }
}
```

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: please tell me how I connect these 3 legs of toggle switch. I want the 0 or 1 from it

Comment: @AhmedAli see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: and will I have to connect 3 leg to `vcc` or not

Comment: No, don't connect the third leg to anything.